# Can I say "house's roof", or only "roof of the house"?

Tags: possessives

For example:
1) House's roof collapsed yesterday.
or
2) The roof of the house collapsed yesterday.

Which of these two is better and why?

Comment: Much better than both of those is ***the house roof***.

Comment: I really thought about it. But people say it isn't correct.

Comment: You're wasting your time listening to those people, because they don't know what they're talking about. It's actually quite difficult to persuade Google Books to show me the results for [***the garage's roof***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+garage%27s+roof%22#tbm=bks&q=%22the+garage's+roof%22&nfpr=1&*) (about 128 hits), because the user interface keeps thinking I must be searching for ***the garage roof*** (about 12,800 hits).

Comment: Your example is just one of many possible scenarios, and the answer may not be the same across all of them. In this particular case, the word _house_ ends with the "s" sound, so the word "house's" is a bit awkward to say. This might make me less inclined to use _house's_. As a similar example, if I worked at the zoo, I might be more inclined to say, "The giraffe's cage needs to be cleaned," but, "The cage of the hippopotamus needs to be cleaned," just to avoid saying  *hippopotamus'.*

Comment: @J.R.: It could be worse. What if that last cage housed several hippopotami, and you were aware of the fact that [*the plural **hippopotami** is now generally taken to be either funny or absurdly pedantic?*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/what-are-the-plurals-of-octopus-hippopotamus-syllabus) Even though we don't normally either write or enunciate the final ***s*** in ***hippopotamuses's***, you might feel you ought to if it was important to make it clear that it was a "multi-occupant" cage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers so no **hippopotamodes**?

Comment: @Andrew - What, not **hippopotamera**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are understandable, but you have to be careful how you construct your sentence.

> House's roof collapsed yesterday.

Doesn't work, because I don't know what house you're talking about. There are millions of houses. You need to say

> My house's roof collapsed yesterday.

Which is a perfectly acceptable setntence.

> The roof of the house collapsed yesterday

Is perfectly clear, but a little more formal. I would still say

> The roof of my house collapsed yesterday

Unless you were in a conversation where the phrase "the house" is unambiguous, such as if you were discussing it with the contractor who built your house in the first place.

Comment: I'll grant that *My house's roof collapsed yesterday* is in principle *acceptable*, but in practice it would be extremely unlikely. Firstly because the only roof most people have is the one over their house, so there's no real need to specify it. But more importantly, ***house's*** is a bit of a mouthful, so you'd tend to avoid it in contexts where an ordinary "noun adjunct" form would be just as syntactically valid: *My **house** roof collapsed*. We normally use that form in contexts like *My **car radio** doesn't work*.

Comment: The indefinite article could also be used: _**A** house's roof collapsed yesterday_. That would be fine in a context such as: _We've been having bad weather in our town. A house's roof collapsed yesterday._ I might not know who the house belongs to; I may have just driven by and noticed the collapsed roof.

Comment: Personally, I would say, "the house roof collapsed yesterday". This is assuming it had been made clear which house was being referred to.  I probably wouldn't use house's. (I am not an expert and have no formal qualifications. I offer my advice only as a native British English speaker)

Comment: If it was my house, I would just say "my roof".  Otherwise, for separate structures, I agree "the boathouse roof" or "the guesthouse roof" sounds best, but then so does "the toolshed's roof".